# How to take value from dynamic edit text in Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have a  RecyclerView with one edit text in Adapter where the editText is dynamic based on object present inside the array, How can i take the value of each edittext ?

```
public class AdapterFastagEditList extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterFastagEditList.ViewHolder> {

    Activity activity;
    List<JSONObject> list;
    OnItemViewClickListener onItemViewClickListener;

    public AdapterFastagEditList(Activity activity, List<JSONObject> list, OnItemViewClickListener onItemViewClickListener) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.list = list;
        this.onItemViewClickListener = onItemViewClickListener;
    }

    public void setOnItemViewClickListener(OnItemViewClickListener onItemViewClickListener) {
        this.onItemViewClickListener = onItemViewClickListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AdapterFastagEditList.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // Initialize view for recyclerview
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        AdapterDynamicEdittextFastagBinding binding = AdapterDynamicEdittextFastagBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(binding.getRoot(), binding);
    }

    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdapterFastagEditList.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        object = list.get(position);
        AdapterDynamicEdittextFastagBinding binding = holder.binding;
        try {
            binding.TextInputContent.setHint(object.getString("BdetailsFieldName"));
            binding.EditTextContent.setId(View.generateViewId());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        AdapterDynamicEdittextFastagBinding binding;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, AdapterDynamicEdittextFastagBinding binding) {
            super(itemView);
            this.binding = binding;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your edittext is an input for user?

Comment: yes ,the doubt is how can I take that input separately in a string?

Comment: you should add a TextWatcher(change listener) for your editText.It's better to put your listener in the ViewHolder constructor.

Comment: can i have any sample code for reference

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        AdapterDynamicEdittextFastagBinding binding;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, AdapterDynamicEdittextFastagBinding binding) {
            super(itemView);
            this.binding = binding;
        

            binding.yourEdittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
              int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
              int before, int count) {
               //s.toString() gives you changes
               //getAdapterPosition() also gives you changed item index

            }
           });
        }
    }
```